# Cancel SVN in a Android Studio Project

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

When I was trying to import a project from Google Code to my own Android project Studio all files from it turned red.

As I got to import the project in Eclipse I'd like to know how to cancel or return to the previous state without SVN project and files in red.

[image]

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In Preferences > Version Control choose none from the dropdown menu:

[image]

Comment: in case anyone is using the windows version it's in "FILES>SETTINGS"

Answer (score 0):

In my version of Android Studio (2023), I need to open the `Dorectpry Mappings` and remove the SVN of this project

[image]